# VueJs radio button with no value turns on all radio input elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I don't quite understand this behavior.

In view when dealing radio input elements that don't have a value attribute set, clicking on one radio button turns all of them on. Why is this?

I know the solution is to add a value to each. In regular HTML this does not happen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <style>
      
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="multiple_radios">
        <input type="radio" id="PC" v-model="picked">
        <label for="PC">PC (Windows)</label>

        <input type="radio" id="Mac" v-model="picked">
        <label for="Mac">Mac</label>

        <p>{{ picked }}</p>
    </div>
  <script>
      const multiple_radios = new Vue({
          el: '#multiple_radios',
          data : {
              picked : ''
          }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't set the value, both of them are `undefined`. So when you click on 1 radio button, `picked` value is set to `undefined`, too. That's why both radio buttons are selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <style>
      
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="multiple_radios">
        <input type="radio" id="PC" v-model="picked">
        <label for="PC">PC (Windows)</label>

        <input type="radio" id="Mac" v-model="picked">
        <label for="Mac">Mac</label>

        <p>Is undefined? {{ picked  == undefined }}</p>
    </div>
  <script>
      const multiple_radios = new Vue({
          el: '#multiple_radios',
          data : {
              picked : ''
          }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must to add attribute `value` in your input. When you click on radio, `picked` will be set. If you don't click on it, the value of `picked` will be unchanged.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <style>
      
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="multiple_radios">
        <input type="radio" id="PC" value="PC" v-model="picked">
        <label for="PC">PC (Windows)</label>

        <input type="radio" id="Mac" value="Mac" v-model="picked">
        <label for="Mac">Mac</label>

        <p>{{ picked }}</p>
    </div>
  <script>
      const multiple_radios = new Vue({
          el: '#multiple_radios',
          data: {
             picked : null
          }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```